# GO: wait for application to quit using xdg-open

Tags: go, kde-plasma, gnome-terminal, google-chrome-os, xdgutils

`xdg-open` does not wait for application to return and quits on exec. I have a script that creates a temporary file and opens it using `xdg-open`, and delete the tempfile once it's done for viewing. However, due to the design of `xdg-open` that does not "wait" despite running `os.Exec(...).Run()`, I get error message that the tmp file does not exists.

I tried using mimeopen and have a handler to get notified of file close (once). These didn't work perfectly.

How can I make sure my program only removes the tmp file after the actual viewer is done launching?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20340146/12749998) out. It is the same question except GO lang specifically, however you may find the answer you're looking for.